# useNativeDriver doesnt work in a very specific animation on Android

Tags: react-native, react-animated

I have been using the Animated API for quite some time now and i'm encountering an error that's hard to explain. I will share code however, can you think of any scenario where the animation would only work when `useNativeDriver` is `false`?

This is what's happening in this case and im only changing the opacity..
However my fade-in animation works fine and its in no way different.

```
fadeout = (step) => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 450,
        useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start(() => { debugger; this.setState({ step }) });
}
fadeIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.opacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 450,
        useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
}
```

I dont see anything off and definitely not anything that would make the animation work on fadein but not on fadeout

On iOS everything works as expected.. I cant imagine the reason why